# Preserving an XMPP connection

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I have a GChome extension that listens to XMPP server.
I use Strophe for BOSH connection.
The issue is "how should I handle connection?" from the XMPP core wiki, I found that the last connected/prioritized client receives messages. And when user is logged in from other place Extension stops receiving message. How can I manage this connection absence. I hope the question is not very ambiguous =).

Comment: When you mention "User is logged in from other place", did the user login with the exact same resource as Extension? By design, XMPP allows only 1 login per user PER resource (If you login as different resource in 2 different places, it'll work.) However, admin of the XMPP server has the ability to force that a user can only logon to an XMPP server at once - It all depends on configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use a different resource for each connection.  The easiest way to do this is to have the server generate the resource name, as specified in [RFC 3920bis, section 7.5](http://xmpp.org/internet-drafts/draft-ietf-xmpp-3920bis-16.html#bind-servergen), by having your client send:

```
<iq id='tn281v37' type='set'>
  <bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'/>
</iq>
```

And watching for the server to respond with the full generated Jabber ID:

```
<iq id='tn281v37' type='result'>
  <bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'>
    <jid>
      juliet@im.example.com/4db06f06-1ea4-11dc-aca3-000bcd821bfb
    </jid>
  </bind>
</iq>
```

Keep in mind that the server may enforce a maximum number of resources, so you might get an error:

```
<iq id='wy2xa82b4' type='error'>
  <error type='wait'>
    <resource-constraint
        xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
  </error>
</iq>
```